# How can I perform a str_replace in JavaScript, replacing text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I want to use `str_replace` or its similar alternative to replace some text in JavaScript.

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = replace_in_javascript("want", "dont want", text);
document.write(new_text);
```

should give

```
this is some sample text that i dont want to replace
```

> If you are going to regex, what are the performance implications in
> comparison to the built in replacement methods.

Comment: Strange nobody noticed that PHP's `str_replace` also accepts two arrays of the same length, where each string in the first array is replaced with the string in the second array at the same index. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5069776/296430 for the only correct function I have found so far that mimics this exact behavior in javascript.

Comment: @JulesColle that answer fails often -- see why/when it fails and a better solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37949642/445295

Comment: If you want high compatibility -- including quirks -- with the php version... take a look at https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/master/src/php/strings/str_replace.js

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using regex for string replacement is significantly slower than using a string replace.
As demonstrated [on JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/replace-string-vs-regex/6), you can have different levels of efficiency for creating a regex, but all of them are significantly slower than a simple string replace. [The regex is slower because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258684/4110233):

> Fixed-string matches don't have backtracking, compilation steps, ranges, character classes, or a host of other features that slow down the regular expression engine. There are certainly ways to optimize regex matches, but I think it's unlikely to beat indexing into a string in the common case.

For a simple test run on the JS perf page, I've documented some of the results:

```html
<script>
// Setup
  var startString = "xxxxxxxxxabcxxxxxxabcxx";
  var endStringRegEx = undefined;
  var endStringString = undefined;
  var endStringRegExNewStr = undefined;
  var endStringRegExNew = undefined;
  var endStringStoredRegEx = undefined;      
  var re = new RegExp("abc", "g");
</script>

<script>
// Tests
  endStringRegEx = startString.replace(/abc/g, "def") // Regex
  endStringString = startString.replace("abc", "def", "g") // String
  endStringRegExNewStr = startString.replace(new RegExp("abc", "g"), "def"); // New Regex String
  endStringRegExNew = startString.replace(new RegExp(/abc/g), "def"); // New Regexp
  endStringStoredRegEx = startString.replace(re, "def") // saved regex
</script>
```

The results for Chrome 68 are as follows:

```
String replace:    9,936,093 operations/sec
Saved regex:       5,725,506 operations/sec
Regex:             5,529,504 operations/sec
New Regex String:  3,571,180 operations/sec
New Regex:         3,224,919 operations/sec
```

From the sake of completeness of this answer (borrowing from the comments), it's worth mentioning that `.replace` only replaces the first instance of the matched character. Its only possible to replace all instances with `//g`. The performance trade off and code elegance could be argued to be worse if replacing multiple instances `name.replace(' ', '_').replace(' ', '_').replace(' ', '_');` or worse `while (name.includes(' ')) { name = name.replace(' ', '_') }`

Comment: Thats interesting and makes sense that pure string replace is faster than regex. It's probably worth mentioning (like in some answers) that `.replace` only replaces the first instance of the matched character. Its only possible to replace all instances with `//g`. The performance trade off could be argued to be worse if replacing multiple instances `name.replace(' ', '_').replace(' ', '_').replace(' ', '_');` or worse `while (name.includes(' ')) { name = name.replace(' ', '_') }`

Answer (score 210):

You would use the `replace` method:

```
text = text.replace('old', 'new');
```

The first argument is what you're looking for, obviously. It can also accept regular expressions.

Just remember that it does *not* change the original string. It only returns the new value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the 'it only returns and does not change'! That was what I was tearing my hair about for a long time till I came across the your comment...

Comment: string.replace('old','new') will only replace the first instance of 'old' in the string.  using a regular expression with the 'g' flag like in realmag777's answer will replace all instances of the string.  text = text.replace(/old/g, 'new') will replace all instances of 'old'

Comment: how about not case-sensitive?

Comment: ^ text.replace(/old/gi, 'new') will replace all instances of 'old' for 'new' not case-sensitive (e.g. 'OLD' and 'oLd' will be replaced as well)

Comment: and some docs with that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 90):

More simply:

```
city_name=city_name.replace(/ /gi,'_');
```

Replaces all spaces with '_'!

Comment: this is a more accurate translation of what "str_replace" does (global). The chosen answer will only replace the first instance.

Comment: Don't forget to escape characters, especially if you're replacing hex escaped: \x27 for example would be `.replace(/\\x3B/g,';')`

Answer (score 21):

All these methods don't modify original value, returns new strings.

```
var city_name = 'Some text with spaces';
```

Replaces **1st space** with _

```
city_name.replace(' ', '_'); // Returns: "Some_text with spaces" (replaced only 1st match)
```

Replaces **all spaces** with _ using regex. If you need to use regex, then i recommend testing it with https://regex101.com/

```
city_name.replace(/ /gi,'_');  // Returns: Some_text_with_spaces
```

Replaces **all spaces** with _ **without regex**. Functional way.

```
city_name.split(' ').join('_');  // Returns: Some_text_with_spaces
```

Answer (score 17):

You should write something like that :

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace("want", "dont want");
document.write(new_text);
```

Answer (score 16):

The code that others are giving you only replace one occurrence, while using regular expressions replaces them all (like @sorgit said). To replace all the "want" with "not want", us this code:

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace(/want/g, "dont want");
document.write(new_text);
```

The variable "new_text" will result in being "this is some sample text that i dont want to replace".

To get a quick guide to regular expressions, go here:
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/
To learn more about `str.replace()`, go here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace
Good luck!

Answer (score 15):

> that function replaces **only one** occurrence.. if you need to replace
>   multiple occurrences you should try this function:
>   http://phpjs.org/functions/str_replace:527

Not necessarily.
see the Hans Kesting answer:

```
city_name = city_name.replace(/ /gi,'_');
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var new_text = text.replace("want", "dont want");
```

Answer (score 9):

hm.. Did you check replace() ?

Your code will look like this

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace("want", "dont want");
document.write(new_text);
```

Answer (score 8):

JavaScript has `replace()` method of String object for replacing substrings. This method can have two arguments. The first argument can be a string or a regular expression pattern (regExp object) and the second argument can be a string or a function. An example of `replace()` method having both string arguments is shown below.

```
var text = 'one, two, three, one, five, one';
var new_text = text.replace('one', 'ten');
console.log(new_text)  //ten, two, three, one, five, one
```

Note that if the first argument is the string, only the first occurrence of the substring is replaced as in the example above. To replace all occurrences of the substring you need to provide a regular expression with a `g` (global) flag. If you do not provide the global flag, only the first occurrence of the substring will be replaced even if you provide the regular expression as the first argument. So let's replace all occurrences of `one` in the above example.

```
var text = 'one, two, three, one, five, one';
var new_text = text.replace(/one/g, 'ten');
console.log(new_text)  //ten, two, three, ten, five, ten
```

Note that you do not wrap the regular expression pattern in quotes which will make it a string not a regExp object. To do a case insensitive replacement you need to provide additional flag `i` which makes the pattern case-insensitive. In that case the above regular expression will be `/one/gi`. Notice the `i` flag added here.

If the second argument has a function and if there is a match the function is passed with three arguments. The arguments the function gets are the match, position of the match and the original text. You need to return what that match should be replaced with. For example,

```
var text = 'one, two, three, one, five, one';
var new_text = text.replace(/one/g, function(match, pos, text){
return 'ten';
});
console.log(new_text) //ten, two, three, ten, five, ten
```

You can have more control over the replacement text using a function as the second argument.

Comment: You are the only one who mentions the function inside replace capability

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, you call the `replace` method on the String object, e.g. `"this is some sample text that i want to replace".replace("want", "dont want")`, which will return the replaced string.

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace("want", "dont want"); // new_text now stores the replaced string, leaving the original untouched
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
text.replace('old', 'new')
```

And to change multiple values in one string at once, for example to change # to string v and _ to string w:

```
text.replace(/#|_/g,function(match) {return (match=="#")? v: w;});
```

Answer (score 3):

There are already multiple answers using [str.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (which is fair enough for this question) and `regex` but you can use combination of [str.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) together which is faster than `str.replace()` and `regex`.

Below is working example:

```js
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";

console.log(text.split("want").join("dont want"));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a equivalent to PHP's `str_replace` you can use [Locutus](http://locutus.io/php/strings/str_replace/). PHP's version of `str_replace` support more option then what the JavaScript `String.prototype.replace` supports.
For example tags:

```php
//PHP
$bodytag = str_replace("%body%", "black", "<body text='%body%'>");
```

```
//JS with Locutus
var $bodytag = str_replace(['{body}', 'black', '<body text='{body}'>')
```

or array's

```php
//PHP
$vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U");
$onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

```
//JS with Locutus
var $vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
var $onlyconsonants = str_replace($vowels, "", "Hello World of PHP");
```

Also this doesn't use regex instead it uses for loops. If you not want to use regex but want simple string replace you can use something like this ( based on Locutus )

```js
function str_replace (search, replace, subject) {

  var i = 0
  var j = 0
  var temp = ''
  var repl = ''
  var sl = 0
  var fl = 0
  var f = [].concat(search)
  var r = [].concat(replace)
  var s = subject
  s = [].concat(s)

  for (i = 0, sl = s.length; i < sl; i++) {
    if (s[i] === '') {
      continue
    }
    for (j = 0, fl = f.length; j < fl; j++) {
      temp = s[i] + ''
      repl = r[0]
      s[i] = (temp).split(f[j]).join(repl)
      if (typeof countObj !== 'undefined') {
        countObj.value += ((temp.split(f[j])).length - 1)
      }
    }
  }
  return s[0]
}
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";

var new_text = str_replace ("want", "dont want", text)
document.write(new_text)
```

for more info see the source code https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/master/src/php/strings/str_replace.js

Answer (score 2):

You have the following options:

1. Replace the first occurrence

```js
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace and this i WANT to replace as well.";
var new_text = text.replace('want', 'dont want');
// new_text is "this is some sample text that i dont want to replace and this i WANT to replace as well"
console.log(new_text)
```

2. Replace all occurrences - case sensitive

```js
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace and this i WANT to replace as well.";
var new_text = text.replace(/want/g, 'dont want');
// new_text is "this is some sample text that i dont want to replace and this i WANT to replace as well
console.log(new_text)
```

3. Replace all occurrences - case insensitive

```js
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace and this i WANT to replace as well.";
var new_text = text.replace(/want/gi, 'dont want');
// new_text is "this is some sample text that i dont want to replace and this i dont want to replace as well
console.log(new_text)
```

More info -> [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function available to replace sub-string from given string with new one.
**Use:**

```
var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = text.replace("want", "dont want");
console.log(new_text);
```

You can even use regular expression with this function. For example, if want to replace all occurrences of `,` with `.`.

```
var text = "123,123,123";
var new_text = text.replace(/,/g, ".");
console.log(new_text);
```

Here `g` modifier used to match globally all available matches.

Answer (score 2):

Method to `replace substring in a sentence` using React:

```
 const replace_in_javascript = (oldSubStr, newSubStr, sentence) => {
    let newStr = "";
    let i = 0;
    sentence.split(" ").forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.toUpperCase() === oldSubStr.toUpperCase()) {
        newStr = i === 0 ? newSubStr : newStr + " " + newSubStr;
        i = i + 1;
      } else {
        newStr = i === 0 ? obj : newStr + " " + obj;
        i = i + 1;
      }
    });
    return newStr;
  };
```

[RunMethodHere](https://codesandbox.io/s/l999n4x23l)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use regex then you can use this function which will replace all in a string

### Source Code:

```
function ReplaceAll(mystring, search_word, replace_with) 
{
    while (mystring.includes(search_word))
    {
        mystring = mystring.replace(search_word, replace_with);
    }

    return mystring;  
}
```

### How to use:

```
var mystring = ReplaceAll("Test Test", "Test", "Hello");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use JS `String.prototype.replace` first argument should be Regex pattern or String and Second argument should be a String or function.

`str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function);`

Ex:

`var str = 'this is some sample text that i want to replace';
var newstr = str.replace(/want/i, "dont't want");
document.write(newstr);  // this is some sample text that i don't want to replace`

Answer (score 2):

## ES2021 / ES12

#### String.prototype.replaceAll()

is trying to bring the full replacement option even when the input pattern is a string.

```
const str = "Backbencher sits at the Back";
const newStr = str.replaceAll("Back", "Front");
console.log(newStr); // "Frontbencher sits at the Front"
```

#### 1- String.prototype.replace()

We can do a full **replacement** only if we supply the pattern as a regular expression.

```
const str = "Backbencher sits at the Back";
const newStr = str.replace(/Back/g, "Front");
console.log(newStr); // "Frontbencher sits at the Front"
```

If the input pattern is a string, `replace()` method only replaces the first occurrence.

```
const str = "Backbencher sits at the Back";
const newStr = str.replace("Back", "Front");
console.log(newStr); // "Frontbencher sits at the Back"
```

#### 2- You can use split and join

```
const str = "Backbencher sits at the Back";
const newStr = str.split("Back").join("Front");
console.log(newStr); // "Frontbencher sits at the Front"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function str_replace($old, $new, $text)
{
   return ($text+"").split($old).join($new); 
}
```

You do not need additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 2021, you can use `replaceAll` can be used.

```
const str = "string1 string1 string1"
const newStr = str.replaceAll("string1", "string2");

console.log(newStr)
//  "string2 string2 string2"
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest form as below

if you need to replace only first occurrence

```
var newString = oldStr.replace('want', 'dont want');
```

if you want ot repalce all occurenace

```
var newString = oldStr.replace(want/g, 'dont want');
```

Answer (score 0):

The in-built function in JavaScript is the ".replace()" function.
The syntax of the .replace() function is as follows:

```
" <string_name>.replace('text to edit', 'text to replace it with' ); "
```

Hence, in a string, the whole or part of the string can be replaced with some other value using this in-built function.

For example, let the string s be: "I practice development with the help of the Coding Ninjas website." And the code is as follows:

```
let news=s.replace("website", "Website");
```

Then, if we print the string news, it will be as follows:
"I practice development with the help of the Coding Ninjas Website."

Also, you can use it multiple times to replace various texts of the string located in different positions.
Like,

```
let news=s
.replace("development", "Development")
.replace("with", "With");
console.log(news);
```

These statements will result in the following output:
"I practice Development With the help of the Coding Ninjas website."

Also, if there is more than one instance of the text you have written that you want to replace with some other text, only the first instance of the text will be replaced.
For example,

```
let news = s.replace("the", "The");
console.log(news);
```

It will only replace the first 'the', resulting as follows:
"I practice development with The help of the Coding Ninjas website."
Hence, if you want to replace all the instances of a substring of the string, you would have to use the ".replaceAll()" method.

Now, if you want to replace multiple substrings with one text, you can use the following syntax of the commands:
let news = s.replace(/practice|development/g, "study");
console.log(news);
The output will be:
"I study study with the help of the Coding Ninjas website."

Also, you can try the following syntax of the command to use the ".replace()" function with regular expressions.
let news=s.replace(/the/g, "The");
console.log(news);

The output of these commands will be as the following:
"I practice development with The help of The Coding Ninjas website."
Here, the "/g" specifies that all the occurrences of the substring "the" should be replaced with "The" substring.

Answer (score -1):

Added a method `replace_in_javascript` which will satisfy your requirement. Also found that you are writing a string `"new_text"` in `document.write()` which is supposed to refer to a variable `new_text`.

```js
let replace_in_javascript= (replaceble, replaceTo, text) => {
  return text.replace(replaceble, replaceTo)
}

var text = "this is some sample text that i want to replace";
var new_text = replace_in_javascript("want", "dont want", text);
document.write(new_text);
```