# how to remove the following text from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace all spaces in a string with '+'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794919/replace-all-spaces-in-a-string-with)

how to remove `,@contacts.Assessor.firstname@ @contacts.Assessor.lastname@` and 
`,@contacts.Assessor - Secondary.firstname@ @contacts.Assessor - Secondary.lastname@` from a 
string in javascript?

Thanks

Comment: `str = str.replace( /foo/g, '' );` where `foo` is the text you want to remove (you'll have to escape the dots and ad-symbols)

Comment: Also duplicate of about 300 other questions - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+string+replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.replace()`

```
string = string
         .replace(',@contacts.Assessor - Secondary.firstname@ @contacts.Assessor - Secondary.lastname@', '')
         .replace(',@contacts.Assessor.firstname@ @contacts.Assessor.lastname@', '');
```

[Also take a loot at this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519368/how-can-i-do-str-replace-in-javascript)

Comment: Consider chaining those `replace` calls... `x = x.replace(...).replace(...);`