# Make discord bot (js) echo message, but removing the command from the message?

Tags: node.js, bots, discord.js

So what I want in the end is this:

user: "*cmd hello"

bot: "hello"

I tried replacing it, searched different ways to edit it, but nothing worked so far.

```
    if (receivedMessage.content.includes("*cmd")) {
    receivedMessage.content.replace('*cmd', ' ');
    receivedMessage.channel.send(receivedMessage.content);
    receivedMessage.channel.send("s/*cmd/-");
}
```

(^found out that you can edit stuff by typing s/oldtext/newtext, but sadly it doesn't seem to work with the bot. Replacing didn't work, either.)

```
    if (receivedMessage.content.includes("*cmd")) {
    receivedMessage.channel.send(receivedMessage.content.text(text.replace('*cmd', ' '))); 
}
```

(I tried more stuff, but I deleted it when it didn't work, and I don't think it'd help, anyway)

I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I perform a str\_replace in JavaScript, replacing text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519368/how-can-i-perform-a-str-replace-in-javascript-replacing-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string.replace() returns a string.
So, `"This is a test".replace("This is a ", "")` will return "test".

```js
console.log("This is a test".replace("This is a ", ""));
```

With that in mind, this is what you need to use:

```
receivedMessage.channel.send(receivedMessage.content.replace('*cmd', ''));
```

Comment: Sadly, I'm getting an error for this.
"ReferenceError: text is not defined"

Comment: Okay, I just tried it without the ".text" and it works. Yay! Thank you!