# How do I get a Discord Bot to delete a user command and replace it with a reply

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Expectation: The bot deletes the user command and replies

Result: The bot replies but does not delete the user command

```
bot.on('message', msg => {

 // Broken
 if(msg.content === 'replace me'){
    
    msg.reply(' replaced');
    msg.delete(500);

  } 

})
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make discord bot (js) echo message, but removing the command from the message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838838/make-discord-bot-js-echo-message-but-removing-the-command-from-the-message)

Comment: @Dshiz thanks for the suggestion but that's a slightly different issue, Elitezen has resolved my issue below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, when you say 'user command' you are referring to the message of the user. In that case the issue is with `msg.delete(500)`.

`.delete()` takes a timeout object as a parameter.
Change your code to this

```
msg.reply(' replaced');
msg.delete({timeout: 500});
```

For an instant delete with no delay use

```
msg.delete()
```