# Replace part of string with other text?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable

`link = 'dog.jpg'`

How do I write code to change link to = `dog.webm` instead?

I've tried `link.text.replace('jpg', 'webm');` but it has no effect?

https://jsfiddle.net/m5Lp6a1z/

Comment: `link = link.replace(...)`

Comment: Use `link.replace('jpg', 'webm')` no need of .text

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I perform a str\_replace in JavaScript, replacing text in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519368/how-can-i-perform-a-str-replace-in-javascript-replacing-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an actual assignment back to the `link` variable:

```
link = link.replace('jpg', 'webm');
```

But actually, a regex replacement targeting only JPEG extensions would be probably be safer here:

```
link = link.replace(/\.jpg$/, '.webm');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Replace Text Then you need to try this,

```
 let link = 'dog.jpg'

 link.replace('jpg', 'webm')
```

you don't need to write link.text.replace

It will help you.