# jquery find and replace multiple items

Tags: jquery, replace

I have a monthly table that needs to be translated for each languages

Something like this (doesnt work obviously)

```
$('.lang-en #monthly th').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Tam', 'Jan')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Hel', 'Feb')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Maa', 'Mar')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Huh', 'Apr')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Tou', 'May')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Kes', 'Jun')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Hei', 'Jul')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Elo', 'Aug')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Syy', 'Sep')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Lok', 'Oct')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Mar', 'Nov'));
    $(this).text(text.replace('Jou', 'Dec')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Yht', 'Total'));

});
```

Comment: Looks fine, what do you mean exactly by `doesnt work obviously` ?

Comment: You say "doesnt work obviously", How so? why doesn't this work? What's the point in this code snippet?

Comment: As a side note @client, consider caching `$(this)`, it's best practise to do so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript string replace array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/javascript-string-replace-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maintain a mapping between the original and replacement strings, and pass a function to [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
var mapping = {
    "Tam": "Jan",
    "Hel": "Feb",
    // ...and so on...
};

$("#monthly th").text(function(index, originalText) {
    return mapping[originalText];
});
```

**EDIT:** If you want to replace only part of the text, you can use nested arrays rather than an object:

```
var mapping = [
    ["Tam", "Jan"],
    ["Hel", "Feb"],
    // ...and so on...
];

$("#monthly th").text(function(index, originalText) {
    var pattern = mapping[index];
    return originalText.replace(pattern[0], pattern[1]);
});
```

Comment: Maybe he has another text in `th`, e.g. `Tou:` or `Huh:ssa`.

Comment: @VisioN, good point. I'll update my answer accordingly. Thanks :)