# How to do "strtolower", "str_replace" and "preg_replace" in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I do this in javascript?

```
$name = $xml->name;
$file_name = strtolower($name);
$file_name = str_replace(array('-','  ',' ','å','ä','ö'), array('',' ','-','a','a','o'), $file_name);
$file_name = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9-]+/i", "", $file_name);
```

Comment: Start reading here [String methods @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Methods_2)

Comment: `$file_name = $file_name.replace(/[^a-z0-9-]+/i, "");`

Comment: And array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/javascript-string-replace-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mozilla has an amazing reference readily available to you. I've included some link in my response below.

Have a look at [toLocaleLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) for lower casing your string. Then move on to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) which is really in many ways very similar to `preg_replace` in that it is primarily based on regular expressions.

Lots of reading, but it shouldn't be too hard! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
toLowerCase()   Converts a string to lowercase letters
toUpperCase()   Converts a string to uppercase letters
replace() Searches for a match between a substring (or regular expression) and a string, and replaces the matched substring with a new substring
search() Searches for a match between a regular expression and a string, and returns the position of the match
```

See here for details: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp