# Replace by the position in a string with an array

Tags: javascript

I want to search a function can replace all "?" in a string with an array position by position like below syntax:

```
replace("WHERE id > ? AND id < ?",[10, 20]);
```

with output will be:

```
"WHERE id > 10 AND id < 20"
```

Comment: Okay. When you have tried coding it and run into a [*specific* programming problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), come back and ask that question. More in the [tour], the [help], and [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is same as this link

[Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)

```
    var find = "WHERE id > $ AND id < $"; 
    var replace = [10, 20] ;
 String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
      var replaceString = this;
      var regex; 
      for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
        regex = new RegExp(find[i], "$");
        replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
      }
      return replaceString;
    };
```