# Replace multiple strings with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to transform this string

```
.jpg,.gif,.png
```

into this (not dots and space after comma)

```
jpg, gif, png
```

I thought that something like [PHP's `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for arrays in JS will do the trick, so I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once), and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069776/702353). I tried it but is't not working as expected. I'm getting a blank string... Am I doing something wrong?

JS

```
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace)
{
    var replaceString = this;
    var regex;

    for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++)
    {
        regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
        replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
    }

    return replaceString;
};

var my_string = ".jpg,.gif,.png";

alert(my_string.replaceArray([".", ","],["", ", "]));
```

[Link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uwgytos/)

Comment: @Hovercraft: javascript!, I've must accepted the wrong tag suggestion withoud reading

Comment: Is there a practical reason to favour arrays and regexes over two basic replaces?

Comment: hwnd: I don't think this is really the same as the question you linked to. If I'm not mistaken, OP would like to understand why he's getting a blank string instead of the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you're trying to replace is a period (`"."`), which is a regular expression for any character. You need to escape it: `"\\."`

Comment: Yeah you need the second slash because javascript think you're escaping the period before it event gets to the RegExp object.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this:

```
var target = '.jpg,.gif,.png';
target = target.replace(/\\./g, '');
target = target.replace(/,/g, ', ');
```

I'm sure it can be done more efficiently, but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your fn to this :

```
function strToArr(str)
{
     var res = str.replace(/\./g, "");
     return res.split(",");
}
```