# Replace [X] with [Y] in texarea on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have a form, where users are to insert musical chords as [Am], [D], etc inside a textarea. A chord letter enclosed by brackets.

I want to prevent users from entering northern europian variations of [H], and have them replaced by english [B] on form submit.

How can I set up a replace function that does something like this:

```
[H] -> [B]
[Hm] -> [Bm]
[Hm7] -> [Bm7]
[h] -> [H]
[h7] -> [H7]
```

I should be enough to globally replace H/h inside a bracket with a capital B inside the same bracket.

Is there a smart replace function you would recommend?

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? What do you mean by "smart replace"? What is the problem with a regular string-replace function?

Comment: By smart I mean the most efficient way to write a string replace function

Comment: Several ideas for performing multiple string replacements have been submitted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once).

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `replace()` call:

```
.replace(/\[H(.*?)\]/gi, '[B$1]')
```

Snippet:

```js
document.forms[0].onsubmit = function() {
    var txt = document.querySelector('textarea');
    txt.textContent = txt.textContent.replace(/\[H(.*?)\]/gi, '[B$1]');
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <textarea>test [H] and [H7m], but also [h] and [h7].</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a Regex--short for regular expression. It allows you to search for (and replace) patterns instead of just literal strings.

To match an `H` chord you can use `/\[[Hh]([^\]]*)\]/g`. This means:

- `/`: Marks the start of a regex (like `"` to denote the start of a string)
- `\[`: Match a literal `[`
- `[Hh]`: Match either `H` or `h`
- `(...)` Capture group: match everything inside and store it for later

  - `[^\]]`: Match anything that isn't `]`
  - `*`: Match the last character zero or more times (zero or more characters that aren't `]`
- `\]`: Match a literal `]`
- `/`: Marks the end of the regex (like `"` to close a string)
- `g`: Global modifier. Makes the regex match every occurance in the input, not just the first one.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0BQtiU/2)

To use this, use the replace function on the input string:

```
inputstring.replace(/\[[Hh]([^\]]*)\]/g, "[B$1]");
```

The `$1` in the replacement value inserts the value capturing group in the regex.