# Replacing multiple words in string

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace some words in string. I have got working solution but I don't think it's the best one. Could you please help me with more effective & clever solution (less code)?

The code is avaiable live here: https://codepen.io/yasAFE/pen/BYOVme

```js
function main() {
      var input = document.getElementById("input");
      var output = input.value.replace(/red/gi, "blue") // how to write this but 
                          .replace(/bad/gi, "good")  // with less code?
                          .replace(/girl/gi, "boy")
                          .replace(/gold/gi, "metal"); 
  input.value = output;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input" spellcheck="false" autocorrect="off"></textarea>
<button class="button" onclick="main()">Transform my text</button>
```

Comment: Take a loot here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5069776/4730201

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
var mapObj = {
     cat:"dog",
     dog:"goat",
     goat:"cat"
};

var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
```

Comment: instead of copying answer from some other question, you can refer the question in the comment itself. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings