# JavaScript Replace specific words in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

How do you replace specific words from a string?
If I want to replace `["hi", "hello", "welcome"]` with `greetings` in this string. (Case-insensitive)

So `Hi there Welcome hi` would become `greetings there greetings greetings`.

Comment: Have you made any attempt?

Comment: Yes but I can't figure out how to make it with multiple words.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Example

```
String.prototype.allReplace = function(obj) {
    var retStr = this;
    for (var x in obj) {
        retStr = retStr.replace(new RegExp(x, 'g'), obj[x]);
    }
    return retStr;
};
var v = 'aabbaabbcc'.allReplace({'a': 'h', 'b': 'o'});
```

Comment: Yes, but that would work if I did it with one word at a time. I want to be able to do it with a big array that could change.