# How to remove a string from an array of strings?

Tags: javascript

Basically, I have an array of strings

```
var array_strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']
```

And I would like to know using that array, how could I find every piece of a string that contains something from the array `array_strings` and remove it.

For example, If I have the string `var hello = 'string1 Hello string2'`

I would like it to output only `Hello` and remove `string1` and `string2`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once

Comment: @Herohtar not what I am asking he is using regex

Comment: He's actually not using regex in the question; however, you have to use the regex version of replace if you want to be able to replace multiple occurances of the string, for example, if you have `hello = 'string1 Hello string2 string1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to `join` the array of strings you want to remove by `|`, then construct a regular expression from that, and `.replace` with `''`:

```js
const array_strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];
const pattern = new RegExp(array_strings.join('|'), 'g');
const hello = 'string1 Hello string2';

console.log(hello.replace(pattern, ''));
```

If you also want to remove the leading/trailing spaces, then use `.trim()` as well.

Comment: I won't work for hello = `'string1 Hello string2 string3 HelloWorld';`, when the words to exclude are `['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'Hello'];`. Result is `World`

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the array and use the string `replace` method to remove the strings from the array. We turn the string into a `regular expression` through the `RegExp` constructor. This will allow for multiple replaces and the use of a variable within our expression.

```js
var array_strings = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'],
  str = "string1 hello string2",

  printStr = (str, removables) => {
    for (let removable of removables) {
    let re_removable = new RegExp(removable,"g");
      str = str.replace(re_removable, "").trim();
    }
    return str;
  };

console.log(printStr(str, array_strings));
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the string value exists more than once in the string value. You would need to use a regex replace

Comment: Thanks for updating, +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have only words as per your example with no commas/punctuation etc then you could also simply split the string and then `Array.filter` it via `Array.includes`:

```js
const str = 'string1 Hello string2 there string3', 
      arr = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3'];

console.log(...str.split(' ').filter(x => !arr.includes(x)))
```

It is a simpler approach in scenario where you do not have complex sentences/string data for which you would need `String.replace` via `RegEx` etc.