# How to convert Arabic number to English in input number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have input type number and need to convert the numbers from Arabic to English once user trying to write:

My wrong shut:

```
<input type="number" class="arabicNumbers">
```

Jquery(js) code:

```
function toEnglishNumber(strNum) {

   var ar = [
       '٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩',' ','-','/','|','~','٫'
   ];

   var en = [
       '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','','','','','','.'
   ];

   var cache = strNum;

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       var regex_ar = new RegExp(ar[i], 'g');
       cache = cache.replace(regex_ar, en[i]);
   }
   return cache;
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.arabicNumbers', function() {

   toEnglishNumber($(this).val())

});
```

Any suggestions or slove?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov No! in Arabic keyboard we have ١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩  I need to convert these numbers into these 134567890  when the keyboard Arabic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your replace algorithm itself work. (Although there is more elegant ways, as you can see in the different answers here).

***But you have 2 problems:***

1 - you take the input value on key up, but since you give the input `type="number"` - the arabic letters simply not been added to the input value, and you have nothing to replace. so you have to accept `type="text"` and then remove all non numeric letters (in the same shot with arabic replacement)

(You can also handle `keyDown` event and `preventDefault` if the `event.key` is not on of english or numreric characters, but in this case you will have a problem with `ctrl+v` that will be rejected)

2 - You return the replacement, but you not put it as the input value. You should do..

```js
function toEnglishNumber(strNum) {
   var ar = '٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'.split('');
   var en = '0123456789'.split('');
   strNum = strNum.replace(/[٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩]/g, x => en[ar.indexOf(x)]);
   strNum = strNum.replace(/[^\d]/g, '');
   return strNum;
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.arabicNumbers', function(e) {
   var val = toEnglishNumber($(this).val())
   $(this).val(val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="arabicNumbers"/>
```

Comment: now it converts from English into Arabic I need convert from Arabic into English

Comment: Yeah, of course, I tried! but convert from English into Arabic!

Comment: There's a shorter way to remove non-digit characters: simply use `/\D/g` instead of `/[^\d]/g`. Also, if conciseness, matters at all, you could chain `.replace()`'s. Besides, if you'll need to scale the dictionary, hardcoding that inside `.replace()` doesn't seem to be good idea. You'd be much better off binding dictionary to replaced pattern (you may refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60453132/11299053) for example).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure about extra (non-numeric) characters purpose inside your dictionary, however, extending the following logic for arbitrary dictionary is not difficult:

```js
const ar = [...'٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'],
      en = [...'0123456789'],
      arToEn = s => s.replace(new RegExp(`[${ar.join('')}]`,'g'), m => en[ar.indexOf(m)])
      
console.log(arToEn('٢٣٤٥'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Unicode character and hexadecimal offsets like:

```js
function toEnglishNumber(x) {
  return x.replace(/[\u0660-\u0669\u06f0-\u06f9]/g, c => c.charCodeAt(0) & 0xf);
}
console.log(toEnglishNumber('٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replaceBulk( str, findArray, replaceArray ){
      var i, regex = [], map = {}; 
      for( i=0; i<findArray.length; i++ ){ 
        regex.push( findArray[i].replace(/([-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|#,])/g,'\\$1') );
        map[findArray[i]] = replaceArray[i]; 
      }
      regex = regex.join('|');
      str = str.replace( new RegExp( regex, 'g' ), function(matched){
        return map[matched];
      });
      return str;
    }

    // Test:
    console.log( replaceBulk( "٦١", [
       '٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩',' ','-','/','|','~','٫'
   ], [
       '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','','','','','','.'
   ] ) );
```

Reference : [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intl.NumberFormat('ar').format("123456789")
> "١٢٣٬٤٥٦٬٧٨٩"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).