# Count string occurrence and replace with string and count - JS

Tags: javascript

I have a use case where I have a string with the same substring if followed continuously should return the string and count together. If not, it should return the same string. We need to check for only one value here, in the below use case it is 'transfer'. Should be case insensitive. I do not care if the string 'Name' occurs more than once.

Example:

> String is 'Name transfer transfer transfer transfertranfser' should return 'Name transfer 5' as 5 is the length of transfer.
> String is 'Name transfer Transfer transfer TransferTranfser' should return 'Name transfer 5' as 5 is the length of transfer.
> String is 'Name transfer name transfer' should return 'Name transfer name transfer' as transfer is not continous.

Please advice.

```js
var temp = "Model transfer transfer transfer transfertransfer";
var count = (temp.match(/transfer/g) || []).length;
let abc;
if (count > 1) {
  abc = temp.replace('transfer', `transfer ${count}`)
}
console.log(count);
console.log(abc)
```

How do I remove the end of the string? Please advice. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: weird that transfertransfer is considered to be transfer. Your code is going to fail for `'Name transfer name transfer' `

Comment: @epascarello why? it is a really good question

Comment: The use case is I am copying a name and while copying appending 'transfer' to the copied name. The original name can be 'Name transfer'. I populate on the UI as 'Name transfer transfer'. However I want to change it to 'Name transfer 2'.

Comment: @epascarello If there are no followups to transfer, need not do anything. Just return the original string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)

Comment: Sorry mate. I checked it but not exactly answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var temp = "Model transfer transfer transfer transfertransfer";
var count = (temp.match(/transfer/ig) || []).length;
let abc;
if (count > 1) {
  abc = temp.replace(/[\s]*transfer[\s]*/ig, '').concat(` transfer ${count}`);
}
console.log(count);
console.log(abc)
```

This way you are replacing all "transfer" string with additional whitespaces. Mind the `g` flag in the replace regex as otherwise Javascript will only replace the first occurrence.

Comment: Doesnt work with Model transfer Transfer transfer Transfertransfer. I want to be case insensitive. But works good for case sensitive ones.

Comment: See updated answer. If you want it to be case insensitive, use the `i` flag on your regular expressions.

Comment: Why does this not return the original string for Model Transfer model transfer? It should only check if transfer is followed by a transfer. If transfer is followed by any other word, we should return the original string