# Make several replacements to a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make multiple replacements to a string (php variable) using javascript.
This code:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var map = {
    "2014": "",
    "2015": "",
    "2016": "",
    "-": " ",
    "ú": "u"
};

var str = "<?php echo $data; ?>";
var result = str.replace(/[<?php echo $data; ?>]/g, function(m) {
    return replacements[m];
});
jQuery('.even_data').html(result);
});
</script>
```

Gives me the error:

```
invalid range in character class
var result = str.replace(/[2014-08-28]/g, function(m) {
                         ^
```

An alternative will be to use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var str = "<?php echo $data; ?>";
  var result = str.replace('2014','');
  jQuery('.even_data').html(result);
});
```

But how can you make multiple replacements?

Thanks!

I tried these answers but they did not work: [Javascript str_replace many at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366073/javascript-str-replace-many-at-once)

Comment: Why can't PHP makes these replacements?  Why does JavaScript have to do it?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I can use php too, I thought it would be easier with js

Comment: What is `replacements`? Where is it defined?

Comment: @user3558931: I just assumed `replacements` was supposed to be `map`.

Comment: Thought as much but would love to hear it from the horse's mouth, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Yes, I it was supposed to be map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to make PHP do this instead of JavaScript.

```
$map = array(
    "2014" => "",
    "2015" => "",
    "2016" => "",
    "-" => " ",
    "ú" => "u"
);

$data = '2014-08-28';
$data = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript Regex, the brackets [] are special characters that define [character classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#character-classes). If you want to use them as literals you have to escape them:

```
str.replace(/\[2014-08-28\]/g, function(m) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
function multiReplace(str, map) {
    for(var i in map) if(map.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        str = str.replace(
            new RegExp(i.replace(/[.^$*+?()[{\\|]/g, '\\$&'), 'g'),
            map[i]
        );
    }
    return str;
}
var result = multiReplace(str, map);
```

It works like this:

1. It iterates all own properties of `map`
2. It builds a proper regex for each property

   1. First, it escapes [special regex characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions): `.^$*+?()[{\|`
   2. Then it uses that string to build a global (`g` flag) regex
3. It replaces all matches of that regex with the corresponding value in `map`

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/utrd3j12/)

Your regular expression is no good. After replacing it with an actual `RE` it should work:

```
    var result = str.replace(/(\d{4}|-|ú)/g, function(m) {
        return map[m];
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JS it would be smth like that:

```
var str = "2014 12 03, 2014, day";
var map = {"2014" : "2012", 
       "12" : "a",
       "03" : "",
       "day" : "sfsdf"};
$.each(map, function(key, value) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(key ,"g"), value);
});
```

//new str: "2012 a , 2012, sfsdf"