# javascript and html character escaping

Tags: javascript, html, encoding, escaping

I have this problem:
I have a javascript, saved in a database field, that is going to be used in a web page as a  href target, e.g.

```
insert into table_with_links (id, url) 
       values (1, 'javascript:var url="blö blö";.....');

// run scripts that use the database values to generate web pages

// part of the generated html code:
<a href="javascript:var url='blabla';..... </a>
```

So far no problems. I have german letters (Umlaute - e.g. **ö**) in the javascript. I shouldn't save the german letters in the database, so I escape them:

```
insert into table_with_links (id, url) 
       values (1, 'javascript:var url="bl%F6 bl%F6";.....');
```

Now comes the problem - I shouldn't store the **%** sign in the database either, because the scripts that generate the web pages cannot handle it properly. I guess you can imagine how these scripts are 3-rd party scripts and cannot be changed.

So, my question is - **can I also escape the % sign?**

Comment: What database are you using?  Many databases support unicode character sets.  Maybe you should switch databases

Comment: it's oracle, but there are just other inconsistencies when I store the german letters. So, it is technically possible, but I should not do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you tryed this? :

```
var str= "remove the %";
var str_n = str.replace("%","");
```

here are the basics http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

then you can use an array of chars to replace take a look here [javascript replace globally with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064047/javascript-replace-globally-with-array)

Comment: IMHO, w3schools is no [credible source of reference](http://w3fools.com/) to *anything*.

Comment: what does it means? w3c is the standard i have no other sites for standards

Comment: w3schools are in no way affiliated with W3C. Take a moment and look at the link.

Comment: this is actually a great idea how I can trick these stupid libraries I work with. The % sign was not the problem itself, but the whole combination %F6, %E4 and so on...
The solution was:
var url="blpercent_signF6";
alert(unescape(url.replace("percent_sign","%")))

Comment: well is simple example, you can do all you need with that ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using oracle's built in internationalization, Oracle is capable of handling special german characters:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_i18n.htm

If you want to handle it on your own, I would suggest doing a string replace to some sequence you know:

```
var str = str.replace(/ö/g,"[german-umlaute]");
```

(the g at the end of /ö/g is to replace all occurrences in the string)