# Replace Multiple String at Once With Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I tried this : [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)
And this : [javascript replace globally with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064047/javascript-replace-globally-with-array) how ever they are not working.

Can I do similar to this (its PHP):

```
$a = array('a','o','e');
$b = array('1','2','3');
str_replace($a,$b,'stackoverflow');
```

This result will be :

```
st1ck2v3rfl2w
```

I want to use regex at the same time. How can I do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: **You can find a replace a string using delimiters ** [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58862890/8427094)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace multiple strings at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069464/replace-multiple-strings-at-once)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var str = "I have a cat, a dog, and a goat.";
var mapObj = {
   cat:"dog",
   dog:"goat",
   goat:"cat"
};
str = str.replace(/cat|dog|goat/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
```

[Check fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L6LB2/)

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution:

```
var a = ['a','o','e'],
    b = ['1','2','3'];

'stackoverflow'.replace(new RegExp(a.join('|'), 'g'), function(c) {
    return b[a.indexOf(c)];
});
```

As per the comment from [@Stephen M. Harris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743683/replace-multiple-string-at-once-with-regex-in-javascript/20743730?noredirect=1#comment63348436_20743730), here is another more fool-proof solution:

```
'stackoverflow'.replace(new RegExp(a.map(function(x) {
    return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}).join('|'), 'g'), function(c) {
    return b[a.indexOf(c)];
});
```

**N.B.:** Check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility) for [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method and use [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) if required.

Comment: This can break if the find strings contain any special regex chars.  Here's an improved version (and also cross-browser w/o polyfills) http://stackoverflow.com/a/37949642/445295

Comment: @StephenM.Harris I have added another variant, that will take care of the edge cases with special regex characters.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use delimiters and replace a part of the string**

```js
var obj = {
  'firstname': 'John',
  'lastname': 'Doe'
}

var text = "My firstname is {firstname} and my lastname is {lastname}"

console.log(mutliStringReplace(obj,text))

function mutliStringReplace(object, string) {
      var val = string
      var entries = Object.entries(object);
      entries.filter((para)=> {
          var find = '{' + para[0] + '}'
          var regExp = new RegExp(find,'g')
       val = val.replace(regExp, para[1])
    })
  return val;
}
```